# force close when assign onclick to button

Tags: android, buttonclick

I am very new in android development as well as in Java. I had developed an application that gets an image url from a site and wanted to download it into the device and later on I would like to enable users to set it as wallpapers. however, I am met a problem when assigning onclick event to a button.
 Once I uncomment the line in red, it will pop up a box stating that the application was stopped unexpectedly. Can someone please help me with this?

```
private ImageView imView = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
        URL url = new URL(xmlURL);
        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
        ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        /* Parsing has finished. */

        /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
        ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

        /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
        if (myExampleHandler.filenames != null) {
            a = a + "\n" + myExampleHandler.filenames + ", by "
                + myExampleHandler.authors + "\nhits: "
                + myExampleHandler.hits + " downloads";
            this.ed = myExampleHandler.thumbs;
            this.imageURL = myExampleHandler.mediafiles;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        a = e.getMessage();
    }

    // get thumbnail
    Context context = this.getBaseContext();
    if (ed.length() != 0) {
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context, this.ed, "image.jpg");
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    tv.setText(a);

    Button bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_imagebt);
    //bt3.setOnClickListener(getImageBtnOnClick);
}

OnClickListener getImageBtnOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        downloadFile(imageURL);
    }
};

void downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
    URL myFileUrl = null;
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int length = conn.getContentLength();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        // this.imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/viewgroup">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button id="@+id/get_imagebt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xxx Get an image"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />  

    <ImageView id="@+id/imview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, you can find more information by using logcat. Open up command prompt (Start...Run...'cmd') and go to your Android SDK directory (unless it's in your Environment PATH). Go to the tools folder and type "adb.exe logcat". Then launch your application and monitor the output in the prompt. It will throw an exception and with that detail, it's easier to narrow the problem down.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  711): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught e
xception
E/AndroidRuntime(  711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{resonet.example.getImage/resonet.example.getImage.getImage}: java.la
ng.NullPointerException

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:2284)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(Activi
tyThread.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1692)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:3948)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(  711):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)

Comment: i got this few error messages including some others such as null pointer.

Comment: I've examined your code and I don't see the direct reason of problem, sorry.  Try to focus on that null reference. If you are using eclipse you could try to run your code in debug mode and examine it step by step? Once again, sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check catlog view for an error messages. If it's nullPointerException then maybe button of id "get_imagebt" is not a part of a file that you set as a content view? Could you also post your main.xml layout file?
Regards!

Comment: i had check the catlog and i found a nullPointerException. thus, how can i fix it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not show the downloadFile() function; it would help if you paste it too. Also, can you specify the exception that you are getting(check logcat)?

A problem, that I can think of, could be missing INTERNET permission in your manifest file.

Comment: i had added the download file function. For the INTERNET permission i had already include it in my manifest file. I am able to get the data needed from remote site.